# Should spring security filters call authentication providers directly?

Tags: java, spring-security

There seem to be two different patterns:

**Pattern #1**
The `GenericFilterBean` does the authenticating itself.  As used by most of the out-of-the-box filters: `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `DigestAuthenticationFilter`, etc.

request comes into filter

filter creates an `Authentication` with `authenticated=false`

filter passes that to a **specific** `AuthenticationProvider` that it references directly (sometimes via an `AuthenticationManager`)

if all goes well, they create a *new* type of `Authentication` and pass back to filter

filter puts that into the context

In this pattern, the original `Authentication` is nothing more than a POJO to pass to the `AuthenticationProvider` - it never goes into the context.
Also, more often than not, the filter also has a direct reference to a specific `EntryPoint` - which it calls at the end.
(I thought this pattern would suit pre-authentication filters?  But there isn't that consistency in the Spring code).

**Pattern #2**
Separately registered `AuthenticationProviders` do the authentication.  As used by most examples online, but rarely seen in the out-of-the-box filters.

request comes into filter

filter creates an `Authentication` with `authenticated=false`

filter puts that into the context.

filter's job is done

spring security now runs through all the registered `AuthenticationProviders`

one of those picks up this `Authentication` and attempts to verify it

if all goes well, they mutate the `Authentication` to  `authenticated=true`

In this pattern, the filter doesn't directly call an `AuthenticationProvider`, or an `EntryPoint`. These are registered externally and apply to all filters.  Typical example of Pattern #2 config:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="myCustomEntryPoint" pattern="/**">
    <sec:custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="myCustomFilter" />
    ...
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="myCustomAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Question: **Is there any logic for when to use one approach or the other?**

Pattern #2 *feels* best.  But I think either way will work, and am unsure which is correct / best / most secure / most future-proof / least likely to conflict with other filters / etc.

If the context matters, this is Spring Security 3.2.5, and will be for token-based authentication where we verify token details (taken from the request header) against a remote service before granting access.

Comment: Also, I know there are off-the-shelf token authentication filters for Spring Security. I am investigating them too.

Comment: Your question is exactly what I see. This story (https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/exploring-spring-boot-and-spring-security-custom-token-based-authentication-of-rest-services-with-spring-security-and-pinch-of-spring-java-configuration-and-spring-integration-testing/)  is using approach 1. It exlains very well what is going on.

Comment: What you've described is exactly what I'm seeing in Spring source vs. online examples, and I have the same question. Somebody should answer this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 3 years, so I think the conclusion is that there isn't a right or wrong way!

The guts of Spring Security haven't changed much since it was Acegi, and it seems to be a mix of different approaches.

In the end, I went with Pattern #1.  I didn't like the fact that Pattern #2 used mutable objects that magically changed from authenticated = false to true!

Pattern #1 allowed me to use two immutable objects (one always authenticated false, the other always authenticated true - but only added on success), which actually felt safer.