# My CustomAuthenticationProvider is not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

[Should spring security filters call authentication providers directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899303/should-spring-security-filters-call-authentication-providers-directly)
I am trying *Pattern 2*, from the above post, where essentially my custom filter intercepts a request, takes all the credentials and puts it in the SecurityContext with `authenticated=false`.
Then my *CustomAuthenticationProvider* should pick up these credentials and validate it.
In my project my filter intercepts the request and does its work but my auth provider is not getting called.

*UsernamePasswordAuthFilter.java*

```
package com.springsecurity.learning.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.springsecurity.learning.dto.CredentialsDto;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class UsernamePasswordAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    private final String END_POINT = "/api/login";
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(END_POINT.equals(request.getRequestURI()) 
                && HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.getMethod())) {
            CredentialsDto credentialsDto = MAPPER.readValue(request.getInputStream(), CredentialsDto.class);
            
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentialsDto.getUsername(), 
                            credentialsDto.getPassword())
            );
        }
        
        
        
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

*CustomAuthentcationProvider.java*

```
package com.springsecurity.learning.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.springsecurity.learning.dto.CredentialsDto;
import com.springsecurity.learning.dto.UserDto;
import com.springsecurity.learning.services.AuthenticationService;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;


@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        UserDto userDto = null;
        if(authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            userDto = authenticationService.authenticate(
                    new CredentialsDto((String)authentication.getPrincipal(),
                            (String)authentication.getCredentials()));
        }
        
        if(userDto==null)return null;
        
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getUsername(), 
                null,
                List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userDto.getRole())
        )); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
        return true;
    }

}
```

*SecurityConfig.java*

```
package com.springsecurity.learning.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        return new ProviderManager(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
            .addFilterAfter(new UsernamePasswordAuthFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/home/public")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

This is my security filter chain
[image: security filter chain]

Comment: No it should not. You are setting the context yourself, you aren't calling anything. You should inject the authentication manager, call the `authenticate` method and the resulting `Authentication` is what you need to store. Basically your filter implementation is wrong. Basically pattern 2 is wrong as that isn't how Spring Security works (check the Spring Security authentication filters and you will see).

Comment: Oh, so does the *BasicAuthenticationFilter* call the authentication manager internally?Because while using http basic my provider is called. Also many github repo and tutorial videos did not call the authentication directly hence I thought spring does it for us.

Comment: Yes. They don't call it because the often extend a Spring Security base filter which does call the method and they only override the methods for getting the username/credentials. See [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#L72) which calls it (as an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is the culprit as you aren't calling the `authenticate` method on the `AuthenticationManager` (which in your case will call the provider(s)).

If you look at some default Spring Security filters, like the [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#L72) and [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L163) you can see that they do call that method and set the resulting `Authentication` in the `SecurityContext`. Where as you just set it without attempting any authentication.

Your filter needs to call it and to have more functionality I would also suggest to extend the Spring Security provided `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and implement the `attemptAuthenticationMethod`.

```java
public class UsernamePasswordAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    
  private final String END_POINT = "/api/login";
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  UsernamePasswordAuthFilter() {
    super(END_POINT); 
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException;

    CredentialsDto credentialsDto = MAPPER.readValue(request.getInputStream(), CredentialsDto.class);
    String username = credentialsDto.getUsername();
    String password = credentialsDto.getPassword();
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(username,
                password);
    // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
    setDetails(request, authRequest);
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
  }
}
```

This will read your object, call authentication and integrate with the other parts of Spring Security (like firing events, session management etc.).

You could make it even a bit cleaner by having your `CredentialsDto` implement the `Authentication` interface. Your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` can then check if it supports it and just cast it. Saves you creating intermediate objects.

```java
public class UsernamePasswordAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    
  private final String END_POINT = "/api/login";
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  UsernamePasswordAuthFilter() {
    super(END_POINT); 
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException;

    CredentialsDto credentialsDto = MAPPER.readValue(request.getInputStream(), CredentialsDto.class);   
    // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
    setDetails(request, credentialsDto);
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(credentialsDto);
  }
}
```

Your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is now pretty simple.

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {       
        UserDto userDto = null;
        if(authentication instanceof CredentialsDto) {
          userDto = authenticationService.authenticate((CredentialsDto) authentication);
                
        }
        
        if(userDto==null)return null;       
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getUsername(), 
                null,
                List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userDto.getRole())
        )); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {    
        return CredentialsDto.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.

For configuration your `UsernamePasswordAuthFilter` now needs to be a proper bean to get the `AuthenticationManager` injected, if you keep the same strategy as you have now you will run into `NullPointerException`s due to no dependencies being injected.